# Resistance and Voltage

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, voltage

I understand that superconductors have zero resistance, but with zero resistance there should be no voltage right? because V=IR

Also, why do diodes have such high resistance but no voltage in the backward bias. Shouldn't be proportional because again V=IR?

Thanks.

Comment: V = IR only for linear devices. Diodes aren't linear. Plus, separate questions is preferred here.

Comment: Yes, you need to focus on one question at a time. And, no, superconductors do not necessarily have zero resistance.

Comment: The answers are here : <https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62664/how-can-ohms-law-be-correct-if-superconductors-have-0-resistivity> .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Ohm's law be correct if superconductors have 0 resistivity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62664/how-can-ohms-law-be-correct-if-superconductors-have-0-resistivity)