# How current can pass through a part of circuit if potential difference between two points is zero?

Tags: electric-current, potential

[image]Since the wire has no resistance there how can current flow in the circuit between points A and B? If current doesn't pass through them then the circuit doesn't have current

Comment: If you have a ball rolling down an inclined plane and then come to a horizontal plane without friction, the ball will continue to roll but there is no potential difference.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise indicated, in circuit diagrams the resistance of wires are assumed to be so low that they can be ignored (assumed zero) in the analysis. This is an idealization.

With the exception of superconductors all conductors have resistance. That said, for superconductors current can  flow with zero potential difference. See also [How can Ohm's law be correct if superconductors have 0 resistivity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62664/how-can-ohms-law-be-correct-if-superconductors-have-0-resistivity)

Hope this helps