# Can a Superconductor have an electric field inside it.?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, superconductivity

I have been reading that an ideal supercondcutor can't have electric field inside it as its Resistance is zero. If you connect a superconductor with a voltage source will it not produce electric field inside .?

Comment: If you take some time to search this site, you'll find that your post is, at best, a variation on questions asked here before.  For example, as I type this comment, I see in the "Related" column to the right of this box, the question [Is current in superconductors infinite? If they have 0 resistance then I (V/R) should be infinite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179374/9887).  That question has been marked a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* have an electric field in a superconductor, but not in a steady state. An electric field  will cause a steadily growing current   in accordance with the Josephson relations
$$
{\bf J}= \rho_s  e  \frac{\hbar}{m}\nabla \theta
$$
and
$$
\hbar \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}= -eV(x).
$$
Taking the gradient of the second  equation and using the first gives us
$$
\frac{\partial {\bf J}}{\partial t}= \rho_s \frac{e^2}{m}{\bf E}.
$$

Comment: Are you trying to say that this electric field would become $0$ soon enough, because of the current response, as the superconductor goes into the steady-state? If that is the case, what creates this electric field to appear in the first place, since we are not applying a field from the outside. All that we did, is put a constant magnetic field outside, and observe the meissner effect. Is this electric field some intrinsic property of the superconductor ?

Comment: In one of your other answers, you mentioned how the Meissner effect guarantees that the magnetic field would be $0$ inside a superconductor at all times. Are you saying that while $E$ can be non-zero when the superconductor is not in a steady state, the magnetic field inside would always be $0$ irrespective of whether we have a steady-state or not. Is that why in the derivation of the london equations, we assume force is related to electric field, and not the magnetic field ?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it will not produce electric field inside - if you look at Ohm rule: $\rho.J=E$. If $\rho$ is $0$, then with any voltage you will not have electric field inside.

Answer (score -3):

I believe they do produce an electric field, because people design electromagnets with superconductors, and an electric field is necessary for an electromagnet.

Comment: An electric field is not necessary for an electromagnet. A current OR an electric field can induce a magnetic field, hence why Ampere's Law has two terms.